# How to build a rank based on threshold in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have a dataframe:

```
val df = Seq(
    (1,"A"),
    (1,"B"),
    (1,"C"),
    (1,"D"),
    (1,"E"),
    (1,"F"),
    (1,"G"),
    (1,"H"),
    (2,"I"),
    (2,"J"),
    (2,"J"),
    (2,"J"),
    (3,"K"),
).toDF("id", "code")
```

I need to rank it based on ids and with respect to some threshold. Example:

threshold = 3

```
id code rank
1  A    1
1  B    1
1  C    1 -- threshold has been reached
1  D    2  
1  E    2
1  F    2 -- threshold has been reached
1  G    3  
1  H    3

2  I    1
2  J    1
2  J    1 -- threshold has been reached
2  J    2

3  K    1
```

How can I do it?

I can create a simple rank:

```
df.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("id")))
```

But how to split ranked groups by threshold?

Comment: Treshold can be any number? Input dataset is going to be big? I have one idea but it requires to move everything to one partition (it may be hard to figure out something which is going to work in another way) and the treshold to be a prime number

Comment: Yes, threshold is variable. Dataset can be very big, TB of data. This is actually a try to split big dataset into chunks by adding threshold which could potentially help when repartitioning dataset by id and rank to avoid having one big partition and as a result to have OOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that does not require to move all data into one partition:

```scala
//get the largest number of equal ids
val maxGroupSize = df.groupBy("id").count().agg(max("count")).first().getLong(0)

val threshold = 3

var f = maxGroupSize
while( f % threshold>0) f=f+1

df.withColumn("tmp1", 'id* f)
  .withColumn("tmp2", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("code"))-1)
  .withColumn("tmp3", 'tmp1+'tmp2)
  .withColumn("rank", ('tmp3 / threshold).cast("int"))
```

Result:

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
| id|code|tmp1|tmp2|tmp3|rank|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|   A|   9|   0|   9|   3|
|  1|   B|   9|   1|  10|   3|
|  1|   C|   9|   2|  11|   3|
|  1|   D|   9|   3|  12|   4|
|  1|   E|   9|   4|  13|   4|
|  1|   F|   9|   5|  14|   4|
|  1|   G|   9|   6|  15|   5|
|  1|   H|   9|   7|  16|   5|
|  2|   I|  18|   0|  18|   6|
|  2|   J|  18|   1|  19|   6|
|  3|   K|  27|   0|  27|   9|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+
```

The downside of this approach is that the ranks are not consecutive.
It would be possible to fix this with another window

```scala
df.withColumn("rank2", dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy("rank")))
```

but this would again move all data to a single executor.

Comment: Is it possible to remove `code` from groupBy? If there are duplicates the approach won't work.

Comment: I think it would be better to use .orderBy(rand())

Comment: Why do you need to do `while (f % threshold > 0) f = f + 1`?

Comment: Yes you are right. You need a orderBy when using rank/denseRank

Comment: About the f: this ensures that the first group has `threshold` elements.